# How can one remove (or at least put into selection) several lines containing Text1 between nearest delimiters, using sed/grep/awk/perl?

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, grep

```
<div>
...
</div>
<div class="row">                _
<div class="col...                |
... Text1                         | unknown number of lines containing
...                               | <div>...Text1...</div> to be removed
</div>                           _|
</div>
```

I know, that if everything is in the same line, `grep -oP '<di(?:(?!<di).)*?\/div>' test.html | grep -ioP '.*Text1.*'` will select for further process, but no idea about multiline.
Mtia.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<div/{:a;N;/^<\/div/M!ba;s/^\(.*\)\n<div.*Text1.*/\1/}' file
```

Gather up the lines between lines starting `<div` and `</div` and if they contain the string `Text1`, delete them.

Comment: Thank you, sed ... file > newfile is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Yes Perl can do this, for quick command-line hacks.  For serious use (programming) see the answer by [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland).

```
perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; /.*(<.*?Text1.*?>)/s; print "$1\n"' < infile
```

With your example as `infile`, the output is:

```
<div class="col...  
... Text1           
...                 
</div>
```

Or if you want to remove the fragment, then

```
perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; s/(.*)<.*?Text1.*?>/$1/s; print' < infile
```

```
<div>
...
</div>
<div class="row">   
              
</div>
```

Comment: no, this perl removing command removes only one line with Text1, but not the complete chunk from <div> to </div>. I'd add that perl ... infile >> newfile is even better

Comment: This could happen if you missed 's'  in /s;  Are you sure you copied the command verbatim?

Comment: @octobris No, missing 's' wouldn't give such an effect. The second perl command removes ```'<', as-small-as-possible-substring-maybe-with-newlines, Text1, as-small-as-possible-substring-maybe-with-newlines, '>'``` or nothing at all.  Are you sure you copied the command verbatim?  Try comparing input to output to make it obvious what have changed: ```diff -u infile newfile | less```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) in Perl to extract the innermost `div` tags which contains text with "Text1":

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '
<sample>
  <div>
     some text
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
         Text1
    </div>
  </div>
</sample>';
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//div[not(descendant::div)]')) {
    #my $txt = $node->toString();
    my $txt = $node->textContent();
    say $txt if $txt =~ /\QText1\E/;
}
```

**Output**:

```
     Text1
```